# Verilog blocking/nonblocking assignment in clk generator with self triggered

Tags: verilog, blocking, nonblocking

Why the following code is not self-triggered?

```
module osc1 (clk);
output clk;
reg clk;
initial #10 clk = 0;
always @(clk) #10 clk = ~clk;

always
begin
$monitor("%0d clk=%0d\n",$time,clk);
#100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

output:

```
# 0 clk=x
# 10 clk=0
# 20 clk=1
```

when used non-blocking assignment it works normally
i.e., `always @(clk) #10 clk <= ~clk;`

output:

```
# 0 clk=x 
# 10 clk=0 
# 20 clk=1
# 30 clk=0
# 40 clk=1
# 50 clk=0 
# 60 clk=1 
# 70 clk=0
# 80 clk=1
# 90 clk=0
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the verilog scheduler.

`@` will wait for a new event, it will ignore any past events. Within the same time step, execution order matters.

`clk = ~clk` is a blocking assignment, meaning `clk` will be update **before** scheduling the next `@`. The `clk` event will be missed.

`clk <= ~clk` is a non-blocking assignment, meaning `clk` will be update **after** scheduling the next `@`. The `clk` event will be sensed.

---

Self triggering blocks are not very common in practice. `always` blocks are not required to have a sensitivity list. They should have at least one reachable time blocking delay (e.g. `@(_list_)`, `#(_timeunit_)`) within the block; else there is a zero time infinite loop and the simulation hangs.

Clock generator are usually implanted something similar to:

```
reg clk;
initial begin
  #10 clk = 0;
  forever #10 clk = ~clk;
end
```

Or

```
reg clk;
always #10 clk = (clk===1'b0);
```

Comment: Where does `@` end up in the event stratified queue then? Is it in the `Inactive Events` section on the chart on page 5 of this paper: http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA_rev1_2.pdf ? Asking because I'm wondering if this graph is simplified and thus missing some queues.